# Allow touch propagation in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, game-development, skscene

Given a `SpriteKit` scene `s`, and one node `a` of type `T` that inherits from `SKSpriteNode` contained within `s`, if both `s` and `a` override any touch handler, the touch event is called exclusively on what seems to be the top-most (highest `zPosition`) node.

**If I wanted the scene and its node to perform two different actions concurrently, what pattern would be best to use?**

In this case, would it be better to:

- Let the scene handle **all** the touches by retrieving the nodes at the location the touch occurred?
- Have a `Touchable` protocol that the scene would implement and have any node send up an identifier to the scene through an hypothetical `touched(_ nodeID: Int)` method?
- Have all the children nodes refer to a static `TouchHandler` object that will perform both actions?

**What would you suggest anything else?**

**Update**:

Given the following code:

```
class Parent: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(Foo())
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //  React to touch, and, for example, move the scene around
    }
}

class Foo: SKSpriteNode {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //  React to touch, and, for example, scale up the node by 60%
    }
}
```

If the user taps on the Foo node, showing on screen, only its `touchesBegan(_, event:)` method gets called - the `Parent`'s method gets ignored.

**What pattern would be best to use in order to be able for both objects to react to the `touchesBegan(_, event:)` callback simultaneously**?

Comment: Your question is overly complex and really unclear of what you are asking. First of all use better variable names in you question then single letters. Secondly are you asking which is better? for other options? or asking if your options are correct? You should post some example code and show what you've already tried

Comment: The point in using single-character variable names is to pose as a generalisation. I guess I'm asking what pattern would be best to use in a scenario in which it is necessary, upon touch, for two objects to receive the touch event and react to it contemporarily. I'll update the question with an example code.

Comment: do you mean concurrently? contemporarily means "living or occurring in the same period of time"

Comment: based upon your above comment I still stand with my answer below. remove any code you can from the scene to the objects class file

Comment: I did mean "concurrently", yes. I ignored the difference between the two adverbs and have used them interchangeably up until now; thank you.

Comment: read my answer below on how to use the touch in your object and pass it though to your scene to be used as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to handle as much of the code in the object class as possible. So I would handle any of the object touch code inside of it's class file and send the touch back to the scene to be handle separately by the scene.

```
class Cat: SKSpriteNode {

    var isEnabled = true
    var sendTouchesToScene = true

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent!) {

         guard isEnabled else { return }

         //send touch to scene
         if sendTouchesToScene {
             super.touchesBegan(touches, with event)
         }

         //handle touches for cat
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly my point: I indeed would have personally avoided having to handle all touch events within the scene and have it call two different handler callbacks. This solution is pretty elegant, thank you.

Comment: you should mark it as correct if it has fulfilled your question